# Python GAE extend db.Property and add a method

Tags: python, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google App Engine - how to extend db.IntegerProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239565/google-app-engine-how-to-extend-db-integerproperty)

This is most likely a more general Python query.

I was attempting to inherit and extend one of the db.Property classes in GAE by adding a method that will return an integer representation of a special String value for example:

```
class DbHHMM(db.StringProperty):

   def to_mins(self):
      '''Convert the string to minutes''' 
      arr = re.split(":",self)
      ret = 0.0
      if (len(arr)==2):
         ret = (int(arr[0])*60)+(int(arr[1]))
      return ret;
```

In my model I have a method that sums up a series of these values eg:

```
class WorkSchedule(db.Model):
    '''todo - core hours for the days
    TODO is there any way to attach a widgeted form to these via newform =  WorkScheduleForm() '''

    time1 = DbHHMM() 
    time2 = DbHHMM()
    total = db.IntegerProperty

    def sum_times:
      self.total = time1.to_mins + time2.to_mins
```

However when sum_times is called I seem to get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'to_mins'
```

Is it possible to add extra methods to the GAE Property classes what are the Python techniques that have been used to prevent this? Am I doing something totally wrong?

Comment: I would have a read on Nick Johnsons blog about creating custom properties  http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Custom-Datastore-Properties-1-DerivedProperty

Comment: See the answers for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239565/google-app-engine-how-to-extend-db-integerproperty/11250269#11250269

Answer (score 2):

Would you mind posting your *actual* code? your "def sum_times:" is not even valid Python.

My guess is that you want this, and it'll work fine:

```
class WorkSchedule(db.Model):

    time1 = DbHHMM() 
    time2 = DbHHMM()
    total = db.IntegerProperty()  # ADDED ()

    def sum_times(self):  # ADDED (self)
        self.total = self.time1.to_mins() + self.time2.to_mins()  # ADDED self...() twice
```